# Bounds on asymptotic behavior of Taylor coefficients of entire functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, entire-functions

It is relatively straightforward to show that when an analytic function has a simple pole, then the coefficients $a_n$ of the Taylor series asymptotically follow

$$ \left|a_n\right| \sim O\left(z_0^{-n}\right) $$

as $n \to \infty$, where $z_0$ is the location of the pole relative to the point of Taylor expansion.  There are similar results (with binomial coefficients involving $n$) for higher-order poles.

I think that I have seen an argument that the converse of this is also true, i.e., if $\left|a_n\right| \sim c^{-n}$ for some $c$, then $c$ is a simple pole.   It is intuitively clear that near $z=c$, the series becomes very close to the series for $\frac{\text{1}}{1-\frac{z}{c}}$ (ignoring a constant factor), so I suspect that this is correct.

Assuming that the converse is true, then all of this suggests that we should be able to derive rigorous bounds on the asymptotic behavior of $a_n$ for entire functions.  At the least, $a_n \sim o\left(c^n\right)$ for any $c$.  On the other hand, we can look at standard entire functions such as $\exp(z)$ and conclude that it's possible for an entire function to have $a_n \sim \frac{1}{n!}$.  It's not immediately obvious what is possible in the region between these two behaviors (exponential decay and inverse factorial decay).

What actual bounds are known here?  Does anyone have a reference that discusses these issues?

Comment: the only condition on $a_n$ for an entire function is that $|a_n|^{1/n} \to 0$ or equivalently that $\frac {n}{-\log |a_n|} \to 0$; the better measure of the decay of the coefficients is in terms of the order of the entire function and is given by $\limsup \frac{n \log n}{-\log |a_n|}$ so the faster the decay, the lower the limit and one can have anything from $0$ to infinity, with $a_n=1/n!$ corresponding to order $1$ as expected

Comment: @Conrad Thanks! Can you give me a sketch of the proof or a reference? I would gladly accept that as an answer.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by proof as the condition that $|a_n|^{1/n} \to 0$ is the standard formula for the radius of convergence, in this case being infinity; as for order any book on entire functions like Levin or Boas has this stuff early on; in general $|a_n|$ can decrease relatively slowly - faster than any $c^n$ sure but considerably slower that $1/n!$ as something like $(\log \log n)^{-n}$ shows - for any sequence $q_n \to \infty$ however slowly $a_n=q_n^{-1/n}$ works

Comment: Sure, makes sense.  I wasn’t thinking. Thanks!